# Javascript Slider issues, outputting result based on drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[Fiddle here!](http://jsfiddle.net/G2xPD/)

Hello,

I need some help with a really simple, Javascript issue. I'm doing a slider which is based on 4 different variables. I've simplified it to show them as Server E to Service G. Each service has a different price per sqm, however I don't want all the services to show on screen. I want the output to be from the selection of the drop down.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider({
        value:10,
        min: 0,
        max: 60,
        step: 1,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
            $( "#d" ).val( "£" + ui.value * 750 );
            $( "#e" ).val( "£" + ui.value * 800 );
            $( "#f" ).val( "£" + ui.value * 900 );
            $( "#g" ).val( "£" + ui.value * 1125 );
        }
    });
});
```

Instead of having #e #d etc, I'd love to have one like #totalPrice which is based on which option they pick from the drop down

```
<option></option>
<option>Service D</option>
<option>Service E</option>  
<option>Service F</option>
<option>Service G</option>
```

Is it possible to make these in Javascript variables and then output in HTML whichever one is chosen. Hope I made this simple for everyone. Any help would be much appreciated :)

[Fiddle here!](http://jsfiddle.net/G2xPD/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things you can do. A relatively simple and clean approach is this:

First, tag each service option with the price per unit surface. You can do this with HTML5 data attributes:

```
<option data-unit-value="750">Service D</option>
<option data-unit-value="800">Service E</option>  
<option data-unit-value="900">Service F</option>
<option data-unit-value="1125">Service G</option>
```

Then from within the `slide` handler reference the selected option and get the unit value to include in the calculation:

```
// not included: rigorous checks (e.g. what happens if nothing selected?)
var unitValue = $("#myList > :selected").attr("data-unit-value");
$("#amount" ).val(ui.value);
$("#total").val("£" + ui.value * unitValue);
```

Finally don't forget that changing the selected value on the drop down should also cause the total to update:

```
$("#myList").change(function() {
    var unitValue = $("#myList > :selected").attr("data-unit-value");
    $("#total").val("£" + $("#slider").slider("value") * unitValue);
});
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G2xPD/1/)**.